# How to show "No records found" message if there is no data available in Fuelux datagrid

Tags: html, css, datagrid, grid, fuelux

In my application, I have used Fuelux datagrid to display a set of records.
Everything is working fine ie. sorting, filter, paging etc. But I have to show "No records found" message if the Fuelux datagrid doesnot have any data.

I have searched a lot but I am unable to find a suitable solution for this.

How to show "No records found" message in Fuelux datagrid?

Help me to find out a solution for this. Any idea would be grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with: `list_noItemsHTML: 'no items found'`.

```
$('#myRepeater').repeater({
        list_noItemsHTML: 'no items found'
    });
}
```

See example in example code:
https://github.com/ExactTarget/fuelux/blob/master/index.js#L651

Comment: For repeater component it is ok. But I am expecting for Fuelux datagrid which is available with previous version of Fuelux.

Comment: Oh, that was before my time at ExactTarget/Salesforce. 2012? You will need to modify the source I believe.